# Laravel 5.7 Pagination Customization

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5.7

```
$users = Student::paginate(2);
```

I was trying to paginate some data with paginate `function()` but am want to show only data no links

Comment: You only want to show data...  Are you looking at showing JSON?  XML?  Comma-separated values?  You're going to have to be more specific...

Comment: Still not sure what you're asking...  But you can try `dd($user)` or `dd($data)`

Comment: $users = Student::all()->paginate(2); loop this in you blade hope this is what expected by you.

Comment: Without full code of your controller and view we can't really help you. 
What's in your view? (Blade template file)

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the way pagination is displayed, first step:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

This command publishes the pagination views under the `resources/views/vendor` directory.

Here you can modify files as you want, the bootstrap-4.blade.php file is the default view for pagination.

You can find more info in the [laravel official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `$students->links()` is optional if yo have a custom blade file showing pagination. However, if you do not need detailed pagination, you can use [`simplePaginate`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination)

```
$students = Student::simplePaginate(2);
```

And then in blade file just loop through it :

```
@foreach($students as $student)

  Show student details

@endforeach
```

If you want to show just `next` or `prev` page links then you can use `$students->links()`, otherwise do not use links at all.

Answer (score -1):

it's simple you must create a function to display your students in your template, add this code in your controller :

```
public function index()
    {
        $students = Student::paginate(10);
        return view('student.index', ['students ' => $students ]);
    }
```

And on the bottom of your template for example views\student\index.blade.php add :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{ $students->links() }}
        </div>
</div>
```

if you want display additional pagination information use the following methods: :

[Paginator Instance Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#paginator-instance-methods)

Comment: Can you explain that further? The given code did not involve any template, and the OP clearly did not want to show links

Comment: it's simple you must create a function to display your students in your template, add this code in your controller :
public function index()
    {
        $students = Student::paginate(10);
        return view('client.index', ['clients' => $students ]);
    }

And on the bottom of your template for example index.blade.php add :

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{ $students->links() }}
        </div>
</div>